# When I tried to instantiate JobOperator then a ClassNotFoundException was thrown. (org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource)

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am starting with a basic Spring Batch getting started example. I have only added one instruction to stop the job in its beggining but I am getting a exception at runtime.

https://github.com/brunogcarneiro/spring-batch-error/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/batchprocessing/JobCompletionNotificationListener.java

```
@Override
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution){
    log.info("Job starting!");
    BatchRuntime.getJobOperator().stop(jobExecution.getId());
    log.info("Job stoped!");
}
```

The exception is thrown when I invoke *getJobOperato().* I cant figure out why this is happening once I am using the spring-boot-starter-batch.

The complete source can be found at: https://github.com/brunogcarneiro/spring-batch-error

The stacktrace is:

> 2021-01-14 15:09:01.963 ERROR 126675 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob           >: Encountered fatal error executing job
>
> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.batch.operations.JobOperator: Provider >org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator could not be instantiated
> at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:803) ~>[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394) ~[na:na]
> at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime$1.run(BatchRuntime.java:52) ~[javax.batch-api-1.0.jar:1.0]
> at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime$1.run(BatchRuntime.java:47) ~[javax.batch-api-1.0.jar:1.0]
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime.getJobOperator(BatchRuntime.java:47) ~[javax.batch-api->1.0.jar:1.0]
> at >com.example.batchprocessing.JobCompletionNotificationListener.beforeJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener.java:31) ~[main/:na]
> at >org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeJobExecutionListener.beforeJob(CompositeJobExecutionListener.java:73) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:316) ~[spring->batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:192) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:166) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:153) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:148) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
> at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchProcessingApplication.main(BatchProcessingApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [jsrBaseContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [jsrBaseContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
>
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Abstr>actAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(Abstrac>tAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext.(GenericXmlApplicationContext.java:71) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator$BaseContextHolder.(JsrJobOperator.java:831) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator$BaseContextHolder.getInstance(JsrJobOp>erator.java:839) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator.(JsrJobOperator.java:163) >~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) >~[na:na]
> at >java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
> at >java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779) ~[na:na]
> ... 33 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [jsrBaseContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [jsrBaseContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
>
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1476) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:489) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> ... 54 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
>
> at >java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~>[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:277) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1541) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1468) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
> ... 60 common frames omitted
>
> 2021-01-14 15:09:02.013  INFO 126675 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [FAILED] in 9s845ms
> 2021-01-14 15:09:02.016  INFO 126675 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
> 2021-01-14 15:09:02.019  INFO 126675 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       >: HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Comment: The answer by @Rakesh should fix your issue. However, I don't see the point of stopping the job just before starting it.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine the ideia is to perform some verification to check if the job should execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below in your build.gradle it will go through.

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.8.0'
```